# Using Fiddler in WIndows Phone 8 emulator on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app. I'm developing this app on a Windows 8 Pro machine. My app is successfully hitting my back-end server. I need to do some debugging though. I turned on Fiddler and noticed no traffic was being logged (even though I know that some traffic should have been logged.) I then followed the instructions found here: http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2013/01/04/Windows-Phone-8-and-Fiddler.aspx.

Unfortunately, traffic is still not being logged. I'm not sure where else to look to fix this error. I can see that traffic in my web browser on my desktop is being logged. However, any network traffic within the emulator is NOT being logged. How can I get this resolved?

I've ensured that "Allow remote computers to connect" is checked.
I used the prefs set command with my machine name.

Thank you

Comment: This may sound obvious, but when you start/reboot Win8, do you start Fiddler first (before VS 2012 and the WP8 emulator)?

Comment: Just tried without any luck. I started Fiddler (as an Admin), then I started VS 2012 (as an Admin) and started my project :/

Comment: There's a new guide on the MSDN Blogs, want to give it a try? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/06/05/configure-the-windows-phone-8-emulator-to-work-with-fiddler.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See the details about how to use Fiddler with Windows Phone 8 emulator
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/06/05/configure-the-windows-phone-8-emulator-to-work-with-fiddler.aspx